# MsBuild Deploy with PackageLocation drop file permissions

Tags: msbuild, web-deployment

I have an MsBuild Build in TFS that is publishing a web zip package.
This is the command line I am using:

```
/t:Build;Package 
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;Configuration=Release;
DeployTarget=Package;PackageLocation=\\xxx\MyApp.zip
```

It is working properly and it is also replacing in the web.config the parameters as expected.
The only issue I am facing is the permissions applied to the package file.
Right now the file is deployed into:
*** \myshare\myapp\ ***
And the folder is set with the permission:
*Everyone: full control*
The package inside the folder has the permission:
*TFSAdmin: full control* 
and nothing else, so I can't open it or copy it ... Is there any way I can avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

So far it seems that the problem can't be fix if not with a workaround.
I have found an easy and simple workaround by executing in the workflow a batch file at the end of the build process.
In the batch file I use the very old **ICACLS** to re-set the permissions:

```
ICACLS \\xxx\MyPackage.zip /GRANT Everyone:F
ICACLS \\xxx\MyPackage.zip /GRANT Users:F
```

Comment: I prefer to use the /reset switch to re-inherit permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Add in MSBuild .proj file:

```
<Exec Command="icacls "\\xxx\MyApp.zip" /grant User:F" ContinueOnError="true" />
```

a sequence of simple rights:
                F - full access
                M - modify access
                RX - read and execute access
                R - read-only access
                W - write-only access

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to make a folder accessible by your website you can place the following snippet in your "PostBuild" events at the very bottom of your .csproj (you need to edit the .csproj file manually via a text editor):

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <!-- grant everyone the modify right recursively even for files and folders created dynamically in the future -->
  <!-- note the use of (OI) and (CI) flags which stand for object inherit & container inherit    these flags      -->
  <!-- indicate that subordinate containers will inherit the same access control element or ace   this means that -->
  <!-- files and folders created in the future within the targeted folder will get the same permissions            -->

  <Exec Command="  icacls   &quot;.\Logs&quot;              /grant      Users:(CI)(OI)M  /T  "  ContinueOnError="true" />σ
  <Exec Command="  icacls   &quot;.\Logs&quot;              /grant  IIS_IUSRS:(CI)(OI)M  /T  "  ContinueOnError="true" />

</Target>
```

Sidenote: If you use publish/deploy-on-remote-server functionality of visual studio to deploy your website, then it goes without saying that the folder permissions will probably NOT be preserved and that you will have to use some sort of post-installation script to re-apply them (probably using the 'icacls' approach again show here). This sort of post-installation script should probably be part of WebDeploy - haven't used WebDeploy myself though so your mileage may vary on this particular aspect.